Three.js glb mesh has weird black surface in certain places and is too bright
I'm quite new to three.js and I'm working on loading a SMPL body model which outputs a obj file and using python module Trimesh I convert it to GLB format. Then I import and render it using Threejs and for some reason the output is too bright and have some weird black surfaces in some places as you can see below in picture. But when I load the model in MeshLab its completely fine.


import {Canvas} from "@react-three/fiber";
import {useGLTF, Stage, PresentationControls} from "@react-three/drei";
import { useCreateAvatarStore } from "../store/store";

function Model(props) {
    const avatarUrl = useCreateAvatarStore(state => state.createAvatarVariable.avatar_url);
    const {scene} = useGLTF(`http://localhost:8080/${avatarUrl}`);
    return <primitive object={scene} {...props} />;
} 

export default function HumanAvatar(){
    return(
        <>
        <Canvas dpr={[1, 2]} camera={{ fov: 45 }} style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}>
            <color attach="background" args={["#101010"]} />
            <PresentationControls speed={1.5} global zoom={0.5} polar={[-0.1, Math.PI / 4]}>
            <Stage environment={null}>
                <Model scale={0.01} />
            </Stage>
            </PresentationControls>
        </Canvas>
    </>
    );
}

This is the code used to output three.js.
What is causing this? How to solve this? Any hint to correct direction would be appreciated. Thanks!
